# Postgres Query with LIKE and NOT EQUAL TO

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query with LIKE and != conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   posts 
WHERE  title LIKE 'term%' 
  OR   NAME LIKE 'term%' 
 AND   post_type != 'type';
```

However, the query results are not being filtered by post_type. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably need parenthesis because `AND` has operator precedence.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   posts 
WHERE  ( title LIKE 'term%' OR NAME LIKE 'term%' )
  AND    post_type != 'type';
```

Because right now without parenthesis you have

```
SELECT * 
FROM   posts 
WHERE  title LIKE 'term%' 
  OR   (       NAME LIKE 'term%' 
         AND   post_type != 'type' );
```